# It is not loading or showing the picture in the Django first page and how to fix menu bar?

Tags: python, django

I have two Questions

First one is that it not showed pix in the first page.
This is code which is in templates/home.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block title %}home.html{% endblock %}
{% load staticfiles %}
{% block extrastyle %}{% static "css/home.css" %}{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
<div id="content_home">

<div id="homeimg">
    <a href="/"><img src="{% static 'img/django_first_page.jpg' %}" style="height:256px;"/></a>
    <h4 style="margin: 0;">This is MEMI </h4>
</div>
```

[It doesn't load the picture that i want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gtC3t.png)

And second question is:
As you can see in the picture that I attached, how it shows the  wrong way that I expect...
Do you know how to fix it?!

[i want to make the yellow box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w8CDr.png)

Comment: What  if you `{% load ... %}` in the top of the file?

Answer (score 0):

Your `home.css` is not linked to the html file. You should write something like this to include stylesheet file:
`<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/home.css' %}" />`

`static` template tag is just a way to provide a url (`href` in case of css or `src` attribute in case of JS files). Details about it here - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/templates/builtins/#static